# ¿Como guardar archivos en carpetas especificas con tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Mi programa necesita permitir registrar y logear 2 usuarios: Maestros y Alumnos, al crear el registro, los archivos se guardan en la carpeta base donde esta el codigo, y cuando trato de logear, estos se juntan, permitiendo al usuario crear registrar un alumnos y entrar como maestro. ¿Hay forma de guardar y abrir archivos en carpetas especificas?

```
def regis_datos():
usuario_datos= usuario.get()
contra_datos= str(contra.get())

print(usuario_datos,"\t", contra_datos,)

newfile = open(usuario_datos, "w")
newfile.write(usuario_datos)
newfile.write(contra_datos)
newfile.close()
print("usuario registrado con exito")

usuario_entrada.delete(0,END)
contra_entrada.delete(0,END)
```

Comment: sip, solo pasa la ruta completa en `open`

Comment: algo como newfile = open("ubicacion de la carpeta", "w")

Comment: sip............